# Initializing a set with a nested tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Consider the following in Python

```
>>> my_set = set( (((((1,2))))) )                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
>>> my_set
{1, 2}


>>> my_obj = (((((1,2)))))
>>> type(my_obj)
tuple
```

I am perplexed by this behavior. My understanding is that `set` expects an **iterable**, and a `tuple` is an iterable, so shouldn't `my_set` be initialized with the first element in `(((((1,2)))))`, i.e. `((((1,2))))`, instead of with the values `1` and `2`?

Comment: Adding extra parentheses does not make an expression a tuple. You also need a comma: `(((((1,2),),),),)`.

Comment: Thanks @DYZ, and if so, why is `my_obj` in my example above a tuple?

Comment: Because `(1,2)` is a two-element tuple, no matter how many parentheses you wrap around it.

Comment: Because `(((((1,2)))))` means the same thing as `(1, 2)`. The innermost pair of parentheses has a comma inside it, after all - it's only all the *others* that are just expression-grouping parentheses. We say that "the comma makes the tuple, not the parentheses" - and you *do have a comma*.